Shape Keys negative to positive range relation
I would like to get advice from someone who is familiar with the internal mechanism of "Shape Keys(SK)".
SKs can have not only positive but also negative ranges. I would like to understand how exactly these ranges are related ?
When we change geometry in SK value +1, we automatically get geometry changes in SK values -1. Can we make geometry changes so that they do not affect the negative range [-1:0] ?
In other words can we get an SK that will scale the cube up in the range [0:1] and scale the cube sideways rather than down in the range [-1:0].
I saw a similar topic, but it ended up creating two SKs + driver.

Shapekeys are relatively simple.  They are per-vertex vectors that are added to the position of the vertex.  In object space.  So if your vertex is it at object space 0,0,1, and you make a shapekey that moves it to 0,0,2, that shapekey is just the 0,0,1 vector.  Each vertex gets its own vector-- one per vertex per shapekey.
When you assign a value to a shapekey, you are just scaling that vector.  So if you scale by 0.5, that vertex's shapekey vector is scaled to 0,0,0.5; and if you scale by -1.0, that vector is scaled to 0,0,-1.0.  Added to the initial position, we get a final position of 0,0,1.5 or 0,0,0 respectively.
The important thing to understand from this, for purposes of your question, is that shapekeys are completely linear: they cannot be used to represent any deformation that doesn't exist along a straight line.  (So for example, shapekeys are not good for rotational deformations, which follow an arc of a circle.)
So, no, you cannot make a shapekey such that -1 scale deforms it with any different magnitude than 1.0 scale; and no, you cannot make a shapekey such that -1 scale deforms it in a different direction than 1.0 scale.
You can make a shapekey that doesn't deform the geometry at all with an input of -1.0, however, by setting the min range of the shapekey to 0.0.  Then, the input scale is -1.0, clamped by your min settings to 0.0, which is then evaluated by Blender on the mesh as no deformation at all.
